# In Eclipse+Android, what is the difference between a Project and a "Test Project"?

Tags: android, eclipse

I copied the ApiDemos sample to my workspace, then tried creating a new project out of it. The New Android Project wizard page is obvious but then the wizard led me to a page named "New Android Test Project", which creates a new "Android Test Project resource".

What is that "test resource" and where I can learn more about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A test project allows you to test your app using [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/); it's not too complete as one would expect but works fine. Take a look at this article: [Hello, Testing](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html). There are projects which also allow you to test your Android apps, and which have more features. For instance, take a look at the [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/index.html) project.

Comment: Thank you very much (and +1, of course). That's the kind of starting point I needed.

Comment: I managed to also find the following resource. I am still reading it, to see whether it is relevant to my question: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_eclipse.html

Comment: It is. Testing is a good practice; I highly recommend you to read about TDD... trust me: it makes you 200% better programmer.

Comment: Yes, it's really awesome btw. Use that and Agile Development, and your projects will be better.

Comment: Highlight from the tutorial: **A test of an Android application is also an Android application**.